# Won't notifyDataSetChanged() launch init{ } in RecyclerView.ViewHolder in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm learning RecyclerView with ListAdapter.

1: I find `setControl()` in `init{ }` isn't be launched after I run `notifyDataSetChanged()` , why?

2: What code should I place it in `init{ }`?  What code should I place it in `fun bind(aMVoice: MVoice{ }` ?

**Code**

```
class VoiceAdapters (private val aHomeViewModel: HomeViewModel):
        ListAdapter<MVoice, VoiceAdapters.VoiceViewHolder>(MVoiceDiffCallback()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VoiceViewHolder {
        return VoiceViewHolder(
            LayoutVoiceItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VoiceViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val aMVoice = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(aMVoice)
    }

    inner class VoiceViewHolder (private val binding: LayoutVoiceItemBinding):
          RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

       
        init {
            setControl()
        }

        fun bind(aMVoice: MVoice) {
            binding.amVoice = aMVoice                
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

       
        fun setControl(){    
           binding.aHomeViewModel = aHomeViewModel    
           binding.chSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener{ _, isChecked ->
                binding.amVoice?.let {
                   ...
                }
            }
             
            ...
         }

    }
}
```

**Added Content:**

To ADM: Thank you very much!

A: Why isn't it a good idea to passing a ViewModel to adapter ?

B: How can I use interface instead ? Could you show me some sample code?

BTW, the following item layout of RecyclerView need to use ViewModel `aHomeViewModel` to control whether the CheckBox `chSelect` is shown  or not. I will set the value of `aHomeViewModel.displayCheckBox` in a fragment.

**layout_voice_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
    <import type="android.view.View" />

    <variable name="aMVoice"
        type="info.dodata.voicerecorder.model.MVoice"  />
   
    <variable name="aHomeViewModel"
        type="info.dodata.voicerecorder.viewcontrol.HomeViewModel" />
</data>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chSelect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="@{aHomeViewModel.displayCheckBox? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE}"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/voiceID"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@{Integer.toString(aMVoice.id)}" />

</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RecyclerView` reuse same `ViewHolder` multiple times that's why constructor does not get called .  So any binding Stuff that should be done for all items should written inside `onBindViewHolder`.

On calling `notifyDataSetChanged` `onBindViewHolder` will get called for positions which are visible on screen and the same `ViewHolder` will be reused (Well it depends). But the thing here is a new `ViewHolder` will not be created each time so you can not us constructor for such operation.

> What code should I place it in init{ }? What code should I place it in fun bind(aMVoice: MVoice{ } ?

Well inside `init` you can find views and set the action listeners. Inside `bind` you do the stuff for each item i.e setting data to the views.

On other hand you should not be passing a `ViewModel` to adapter that's not a good idea, Use an `interface` instead.

**Why you don't pass ViewModel to Adapter**
Well ultimately `ViewModel` is just a class so you can pass it and it won't give any error . The reasons i can think of right now to not do it are follows :-

1. By Passing `ViewModel` yo are tightly coupling the adapter to a single `ViewModel` i.e in turns Activity or a fragment. Now you can not reuse this Adapter any any other place
2. Also the whole point of having a `ViewModel` is to observe the data stream which don't usually happen inside Adapter.

Remember one thing `ViewModel`(LiveData) is not a replacement of Callback interface. So you should be using callback interface here Since you do not need a lifecycle component here.

So instead of passing `ViewModel` direactly pass the dataset to the adapter And if you need to notify the `Activity` or `Fragment` on the actions (click, long click) use a Interface.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: If you pass the viewmodel inside the adapter so you can do stuff in you activity its totally wrong. You must pass an interface which will be implemented inside ur activity

Answer (score 0):

`init` will be called once when the `ViewHolder` is created. Thats why `RecyclerView` has the word recycle in it. It will reuse its objects. Therefor `init` will only be called once in the Lifecycle of `ViewHolder`. `bind` will be called, when the content is visible (or near visible). Call `setControl` in `bind`.